# How did rebel fighters get past the Scarif shield?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

In *Star Wars: Rogue One*, during the battle of Scarif and just before the shield was destroyed, a rebel squadron somehow showed up and engaged in battle inside the shield.

How did that first squadron get through the planetary shield?

Comment: I don't know why this question has been closed. It's perfextly clear what OP is asking.

Comment: @Valorum - I *guess* I can see why. In it's original state there wasn't an actual question asked, but I don't agree with the close though. Occasionally posts like that tend to be more "rant-y", but that's not the case here IMO. Unfortunately people seem to be quick on the close flags even when a question can easily be interpreted from the post. Happens a lot over on SO as well...

Comment: Whenever you see something like that, a wizard did it.

Comment: it's patently obvious in the film, hence my downvote. Krennic left the shield open when he arrived. Thus, the shield was open, the fighters got in, then Krennic ordered the shield closed. The shield being closed is the last bit of MacGuffin in the film, all the drama around getting it re-opened so the signal can get out

Comment: Oh boy, I feel dumb to have missed that. Though it is a pretty ridiculous premise to expect that situation not to be better planned for by the Imperial security forces.

Answer (score 33):

A few fighters got through before the shield gate was closed: